# templates for post only

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

i have a catefory template that loops through my posts with 'blog' categorys and styles them into a thumbnail type list with an excerpt only. i then use a permalink to allow someone to go to read the post fully. however now i have no idea how to handle this in terms of a template file.

here is my category blog template page...
http://louiseguchi.co.uk/?category_name=blog

at the moment the permalink goes to this structure of url...
http://louiseguchi.co.uk/?p=202

as you can see my normal header featuring my vimeo showreel is the deafult header. i dont know what template is being used here and or how to make the right one what would it be called?

Many thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may misunderstand you but if you are unsure what template generates this or that page, you may install a plugin that will tell you. E.g. The plugin [What template am I viewing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/what-template-file-am-i-viewing/).

If you are unsure what OTHER templates might help you - you may consult the [template hierarchy section on wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). It has got a picture of all the templates that wordpress may use when creating a page. Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks consulting the template hierarchy revealed that what i wanted was single.php and this has worked great. many thanks for you time to answer my amateur question!